# Find the derivative of this equation.

Tags: calculus

I need help on deriving this equation $(\cos(x)+\cot(x))(\cos(x)-\cot(x))$, I do understand that one must use the product rule, but I do not understand why the answer is $y'=0$, can someone please explain this to me

Comment: That expression's derivative is not $0$.

Comment: That's a function or expression, not an equation.

Comment: Technicality: That's an _expression_, not an _equation_. $^\textrm{Sorry.}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
   f(x)  &= \cos^2 x - \cot^2 x \\
   f'(x) &= -2\cos x \sin x - 2\cot x\cdot\frac{-1}{\sin^2 x}\\ 
         &= -2\cos x \sin x + \frac{2 \cos x}{\sin^3 x} \\
         &= 2\cos x(\sin^{-3}x - \sin x)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: By $\sin^{-3}x$, you mean $(\sin x)^{-3}$? (I'm only asking, because $\sin^{-1}x\neq(\sin x)^{-1}$, to the confusion of trig students everywhere.)

Comment: Yes, I meant $1/sin^3x$ and agree that fractional representation is better to avoid ambiguity.